# FluentValidation - with AutoValidation, how to not throw an exception in certain cases

Tags: fluentvalidation

We're using FluentValidation 11.7.1 and FluentValidation.AspNetCore 11.3.0 in our .net 7 web api project to validate all incoming requests. We're still using the auto-validation, and have it configured in Program.cs like so:

```
    services
        .AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()
        .AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
```

and then we also set up the InvalidModelStateFactory like so:

```
        services.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            // This is here to make sure that validation errors caught in the request pipeline get logged
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                ValidationProblemDetails problemDetails = new(context.ModelState)
                {
                    Title = "Validation Error",
                    Type = "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807",
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Detail = "The request contained validation error(s)"
                };
                // ... log the errors here ...
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
            };
        });
```

With this setup, all validation errors will cause the request to abort, which is the behavior we wanted ... until now. Now we have a case where we'd still like to validate the request and log any validation errors, but do **not** want to abort the request. We instead need to continue and let the request finish processing as if no validation errors were found.
I'm not sure the best way to do this. The only approach I see in the FV documentation is to override `RaiseValidationException` and in there just **not** throw an exception. I feel like I'm missing a better way of accomplishing this. Any thoughts?